# Creating a long precision number in C#

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, precision

I have a bunch of code written by someone else for a statistics package, like so:

```
float myValue = 0.0f;
```

That makes myValue a single point precision number. Is there a way to make it go to five decimal places?

Is this the correct way:

```
 float myValue = 0.00000f;
```

Comment: floats have a precision of 7 digits

Comment: yeah that is what i thought to both of you, just double checking, thx

Comment: Note that float and double data types are still subject to rounding errors due to the IEEE 754 specification - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point - If appropriate, you might want to use decimal. For a description of rounding errors, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is to specify the value is float

```
From msdn : By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the
assignment operator is treated as double. Therefore, to initialize a float
variable, use the suffix f or F
```

Both declarations are the same. If you want round to five decimal point by using Math.Round()

```
Math.Round(45.45672234, 5);
Ans : 45.45672
```

Comment: When piping it through Math.Round, you change the type to a double.